# debugging USB read

Tags: winapi, usb, ntdll, deviceiocontrol

I am debugging some code that uses a 3rd party 64-bit DLL to access a custom USB device. My environment is Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1 x64.

According to an incomplete and unreliable document, the DLL is supposed to issue a USBDEVFS_CONTROL ioctl to read 1 byte from a connected USB device. The definition involves

```
ctrl.bRequestType = bmRequestType;
ctrl.bRequest     = bRequest;
ctrl.wValue       = wValue;
ctrl.wIndex       = wIndex;
ctrl.data         = ByteArray;
ctrl.wLength      = 64;
ctrl.timeout      = 1000;
```

Here `bmRequestType`, `bRequest`, `wValue`, and `wIndex` are constants provided by the device manufacturer, and `ByteArray` is a `uint8_t[64]` buffer that contains the specific command.

The DLL accepts application-specific parameters, packs them into the `ByteArray`, and calls `ksproxy.ax`->`Kernelbase.dll`->`ntdll.dll`. The last disassembly I can see in user mode, is

```
mov     r10,rcx
mov     eax,47h
syscall
ret
```

With step-by-step debugger, I can easily see that the `ByteArray` is constructed exactly as it is supposed to be, according to the document. But I cannot find the [`usbdevfs_ctrltransfer`](http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structusbdevfs__ctrltransfer.html) structure, or its Windows equivalent.

Specifically, we suspect that the value of **`wIndex`**, specified in the document, applies to an older version of hardware, and that the Windows DLL actually uses `0x0400` instead of `0x0402`.

Any hint (including hardware or software USB sniffers, emulators, etc.) how we can try to verify this *unsigned short* will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Reading https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/how-to-reverse-engineer-simple-usb-device-windows-linux and https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/usb-dongle-traffic-monitoring. It looks like these tools are not compatible with Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: I prefer this USB hardware analyzer for sniffing packets, [Ellisys USB Explorer 200](http://www.ellisys.com/products/usbex200/), add on decoding and you have yourself a nice tool for reverse engineering and debugging USB easily.

Comment: I like the [Beagle 12](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/).

Comment: The USB device filesystem (USBDEVFS) is a Linux thing so I don't understand why you are even talking about it for a piece of Windows software.  If this device you have uses winusb.sys as the driver, then the 3rd-party DLL should be making calls to setupapi.dll and winusb.dll.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: I don't see calls to `setupapi.dll` and `winusb.dll` in my debugger; instead, I can trace `ksproxy.ax`->`Kernelbase.dll`->`ntdll.dll`. You are right that USBEVFS is not for Windows. But I expected there to be a Windows equivalent for Linux `USBDEVFS_CONTROL` ioctl (`0xC0185500`).

Comment: If you look at the properties of this thing in the Device Manager, what drivers do you see in the list?  Does it say winusb.sys or something else?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, it doesn't look even similar to what you describe. When I connect the device to my laptop, I see a new `USB Camera` under *Imaging devices*, which is totally expected, because the device is a camera. I also find a new `USB Composite Device`, `USB Printing Support`, and `No Printer Attached` -- all three under *USB controllers*. None lists `setupapi.dll` or `winusb.dll`. I would be very much obliged if you have any hint on how this is related to `USBDEVFS_CONTROL` ioctl.

Answer (score 0):

While working on the Xbox OS and peripherals, we always used the [CATC Chief](http://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/manuals/usbchiefusersmanual.pdf) USB capture hardware, which works as a man-in-the-middle device (it looks like it has been superseded by the [Teledyne LeCroy](http://teledynelecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/) protocol analyzers).

The traffic capture capabilities were indispensable in diagnosing hardware and software errors (bulk, HID, isoch).

Sample capture view (from the manual):

[image: USB Capture Trace]